# Configure Apache to run ELF executables

Tags: apache, cgi

I've searched for this for a while but have not been able to find a solution. How can I configure Apache to run any ELF executable in the web root as a CGI program? For example, if I write and compile a C program and place it as `/var/www/something`, I want to be able to visit `http://localhost/something` and have Apache run the program, outputting the result, instead of prompting me to download the binary.

Edit: I know how to run CGI programs, and those outside of `cgi-bin`, I just want to find out how to run ELF executables with no extension such as `.cgi`, possibly using Apache to detect the magic of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the files directive to whitelist your executable names?

```
<files something>
  SetHandler cgi-script
</files>
```

Or better, can you put all your executables into a single known subdirectory?

```
<location /exec>
  SetHandler cgi-script
</location>
```

Comment: I think you might be able to use mod_mime_magic for this, but I didn't have time to investigate very far into it.